# Editing the context menus for folders and files in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu

In Windows XP, with SP 2, is there a way to make changes to the right-click menus for folders and files--e.g., to add, delete, or reorder items and dividing lines?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to edit context menu items. Additionally, you can try [Mmm](http://hace-software.com/mmm.shtml) to go deeper with the context menus.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [File Menu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html)