# How can I clean up my Windows Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editor for Windows Explorer’s context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/155271/editor-for-windows-explorers-context-menu)

So when I right-click a file in Explorer I have a bunch of added menu items.

There are a few I would like to keep however. How can I remove the ones that I want to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editor for Windows Explorer's context menu](http://superuser.com/questions/155271/editor-for-windows-explorers-context-menu) and http://superuser.com/questions/140441/editing-the-context-menus-for-folders-and-files-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html); <sub>note that this file is clean, Sophos gives [a false positive](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/adware-and-puas/NirSoft.aspx)...</sub>

[image: ShellExView screenshot]

An alternative is to use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which allows you to clean up the same and a lot more...

[image]

Comment: @NamGiVU: False positive, have you even read what `NirSoft` is? No, you haven't, so you can't conclude that it's a virus. [Read up here](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/adware-and-puas/NirSoft.aspx) and you'll see that it is a Hacking Tool and **even has aliases saying `not-a-virus`**. Of course, normal users don't need shell extension viewers thus it is a *Potentionally* Unwanted Application. Real viruses trigger multiple scanners, anyway...

Comment: Awesome busted! I didn't double-check it. You enlarge me. Thank you. By the way, I think virustotal should provide better service - put some icon to link to the page like yours so as user like me would be noticed of such false alarm.

Comment: @NamGiVU: True; on the other hand, I learned that Sophos seems to be nice to find potential tools on computers (to see if someone was messing around). Thanks for that! Also nice that you consequently verify your downloads with VirusTotal... :)

Answer (score 3):

Most programs that nest in the context menu offer an option of removing that. Usually found in the program's properties as something like "Add context menu option".

---

Just found this from http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article02-026:

> - Select Folder Options from the Tools menu in My Computer or Explorer, and
>     click the File Types tab.
> - Highlight the desired file type, and click Advanced.
> - Here, you can specify a new name for this file type (to be listed in the
>     type column in Explorer), as well as
>     the default icon for files of this
>     type.
> - In the box entitled Actions, is a list of the customizable context menu
>     items. The bold item is the default
>     (the action carried out when you
>     double-click on a file of this type).
> - You can add new items, change the default action, and remove unwanted
>     items here. For new items, simply
>     specify the program with which you
>     want the action caried out.

Might be worth a try also.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work on Windows 7.

Comment: Okay too bad ;) Good luck with finding something! Suggest you check out one of the other answers! They look promising! =)

Answer (score 2):

Try Menu Maid, easier to use than ShellExView for this sort of thing.

http://www.sdsoftware.org/software/menumaid/

.
[image]

Comment: Your link has broken, can you fix it?

Comment: Try it again, fixed.